# Sending the same variable to multiple client processes using a socket

Tags: c, sockets

I've been scouring the internet for more information on sockets in C, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

So here's the problem:

- We have to create a server that starts up two client processes that play a game.
- It's a simple memory-style game that takes two numbers as inputs

  - if both of those two numbers correspond to the same letters,
  - then that spot is set to white space
  - else set to the letter that it corresponded to.
- Where the trouble comes in is sending the same array to both clients.
- Both clients can play the game fine by themselves, however, they can't play the game together.
- Player 1's guesses do not appear on player 2's console.

So my question is: how can you update the array in each child process so that the same array is written to both clients?

I'm not really looking for any sample code or anything, but more of a conceptual answer/ more resources on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: You can look resource regarding IPC (inter-process communication) such as pipe, message queue, socket, shared memory, just to name a few.

Comment: Sending data on sockets is about sending streams of bytes, eg To send 4 int array `sendData(&array,sizeof(int)*4)` and don't forget to check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

A rough pseudo code concept would be

## Initialization

```
connectPlayers();
if(player1)
{
   generateGame();
    do
    {
        bytesSent = sendArray to other players
    } while (!allBytesSent)
}
else
{

   do
   {
      bytesRead = readArray from server
   } while (!allBytesRead)
}
```

## Game Loop

```
while(!gameComplete)
{
   if(!firstTime through as player 1)
   {
       waitforyourTurn();
       read and update Game State; //reads another players guess and update array
   }
   result = doAGuess();
   sendGuess(result); //sends guess to other player
   passTurnToNextPlayer();
}
```